# How to "open at login" feature for multiple users programatically in OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos

I have an application which is launching under root. And I need to get a list of items which are "login items"  (application which were set as "Open in Login") for adding/removing items for multiple users.

Here is a code how I do for particular user:

```
LSSharedFileListRef loginItems = LSSharedFileListCreate(NULL, kLSSharedFileListSessionLoginItems, NULL);
UInt32 seed = 0U;

NSArray *currentLoginItems = (__bridge NSArray *)(LSSharedFileListCopySnapshot(loginItems, &seed));

for (id itemObject in currentLoginItems) {

    CFURLRef url = NULL;
    LSSharedFileListItemRef item = (__bridge LSSharedFileListItemRef)itemObject;
    OSStatus status = LSSharedFileListItemResolve(item, 0, (CFURLRef*) &url, NULL);
    NSString *urlPath = [(__bridge NSURL*)url path];

    if (status == errSecSuccess && [urlPath rangeOfString:anAppName].location != NSNotFound) {

        status = LSSharedFileListItemRemove(loginItems, item);
        result = YES;
        break;
    }

    CFRelease(url);
}
```

When I set kLSSharedFileListGlobalLoginItems it returns me empty list.

As I described above I need to add/remove startup items (e.g. Calendar.app) for all users.

Answer (score 1):

The list is empty because there is nothing there. This is not uncommon. I've not had entries there for some time. The list is in the file `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginitems.plist`. You can verify it's content using `plutil -p /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginitems.plist` - if the file isn't there then you don't have any global login items.

The current recommendation is to use a global LaunchAgent, rather than adding entries to the this list. This is documented in the header in 10.9 where it mentions:

```
/*
 *  kLSSharedFileListGlobalLoginItems   *** DEPRECATED ***
 *
 *  Deprecated:
 *    Use a LaunchAgent instead.
 *
 *  Availability:
 *    Mac OS X:         in version 10.5 and later in CoreServices.framework
 *    CarbonLib:        not available
 *    Non-Carbon CFM:   not available
 */
```

you put LaunchAgents into /Library/LaunchAgents - one per program to launch. It's a standard property file. An example would look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
 <dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>com.apple.calendar</string>
  <key>Program</key>
  <string>/Applications/Calendar.app/Contents/MacOS/Calendar</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
   <string>/Applications/Calendar.app/Contents/MacOS/Calendar</string>
  </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
  <key>LaunchOnlyOnce</key>
  <true/>
 </dict>
</plist>
```

This says to launch calendar on `RunAtLoad` (i.e. when the user logs on because it's in `LaunchAgents`), and only once (`LaunchOnlyOnce`).